# MySQL оператор LIKE + два дополнительных условия (OR)

Tags: like, mysql

Ребят, подскажите, пожалуйста, как составить корректно запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE Col1 LIKE 'D%' AND Code > 5 AND Code = 0 ;
```

Возвращает 0.

А если так:

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE Col1 LIKE 'D%' AND Code > 5 ;
```

то возвращает нужные позиции, но нужно включительно и с `Code = 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Col1 LIKE 'D%' AND (Code = 0 OR Code > 5);
```

Comment: Как все просто. Спасибо тебе :).

Comment: @oscar2000 Не за что. На будущее. Посмотрите на [приоритет операторов mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operator-precedence.html)